# Generating missing Webservice Proxy Class

Tags: java, eclipse, webservice-client, wsdl2java, axis

We are using `axis` webservices in our projects.

Up to now we generated our webservice clients within `Eclipse`. We choose `New -> Other -> Web Services -> Web Service Client`. Afterwards we selected the wsdl, changed the step to develop client and choose the axis web service runtime.

Besides the elements Eclipse generates 5 stubs/proxy classes.

- MyService_PortType
- MyService_Service
- MyService_ServiceLocator
- MyServiceProxy
- MyServiceSOAPStub

As a best practice we now try to script that proxy generation with axis `wsdl2java`.

We are using:

```
wsdl2java.bat -uri ..\MyService.wsdl -S . -s
```

This generates:

- MyService_PortType
- MyService_Service
- MyService_ServiceLocator
- MyServiceSOAPStub

The `MyServiceProxy` is missing. Unfortunately we coded against this proxy which is basically a wrapper around the other 4 clases. Without the proxy class I have to exchange legacy code that is using this proxy.

How can I generate this missing proxy class. I checked the [wsdl2java documentation](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/CodegenToolReference.html) however I couldn't figure out what option I need to set. I'm wondering if the proxy isn't part of the axis generation and a custom class from the `Eclipse`.

EDIT:
I just noticed a [different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825353/how-to-use-service-servicelocator-porttype-porttypeproxy-and-stub-to-create-a-ja) that lists the proxy as well. Probably its not RAD specific it could be an Eclipse feature.